# Primitive types as parameters using message contract WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I am making a WCF service and there exists a client that will be communicating with the service and the client expects the responses to be at given format.

That is why I used MessageContract. However the client is putting primitive types as parameters.

Is there no way I can make my service accept primitive types as parameters using MessageContract?

Here is the code for the contract I have created.

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    contentListResult getContentList();
}

//SVC 
public contentListResult getContentList()
{  
   //Implementation
}

//Classes

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class contentListResult
{
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public contentList contentList { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class contentList
{
   //Some properties
}
```

This all works but when I try to put parameters in the service (int Id, string foo) it brakes because when using message contract apparently the parameters needs to be objects.

Is there no way to go around this?

Comment: what exactly is primitive types here?Can you show the code of Messagecontract that you have designed?

Comment: I updated the question with the code, thanks.

Comment: have you tried decorating with knowntype attribute?

Comment: No I am not familiar with that I will look it up.

Comment: Ok just to make sure we are at the same page, I need to be able to call the service like so client.getContentList(int, string, string).

I dont understand how decorading with known type helps with that.

Comment: Your operationcontract   contentListResult getContentList(); doesnt define anything about any parameters.

Comment: yes I know, maybe I was not clear. But I would like to have the service as it is  but add parameters to getContentList()

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the contentlist with knowntype.

```
 [KnownType(typeof(contentList))] 
 [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class contentListResult
    {
       [MessageBodyMember]
       public contentList contentList { get; set; }
    }

    public class contentList
    {
       //Some properties
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was looking for a workaround to be able to take parameters in the service.

The workaround is to declare an object and decorate it with [MessageContract] and the properties with [MessageHeader].